# Sorting of arrays based on another array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, sorting, gpu

I have two arrays:

```
data_array=[4.4, 7.2, 10.1, 1.1, 5.5, 8.3, 2.2, 6.2, 3.3, 9.1, 1.3]
test_array=[2, 5, 9, 4, 10, 8, 7, 3, 6, 1, 1]
```

Required Output:

```
[2.2, 5.5, 9.1, 4.4, 10.1, 8.3, 7.2, 3.3, 6.2, 1.1, 1.3]
```

i.e., I need to arrange the data_array based on each element wise smallest difference of the two arrays in a **unique manner** (meaning: in the example test_array, value '1' is present twice whoes smallest difference->0.1 with values of data_array, hence 1.1 in output array, but for second value '1' in the test_array it should take the next smallest difference-> 0.3, hence 1.3 in output array)

This is an example. I want to execute this for **arrays of larger lengths** (in thousands/millions)

Thank you in advance

Solution in MATLAB, Python or any other efficient medium is appreciated!

```
def method1(A, B):
    result = np.empty_like(A)
    for i, val in tqdm(enumerate(A), desc="Processing", unit="iteration", unit_scale=True):
        closest_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(B- val))
        result[i] = B[closest_idx]
        comp_arr = np.delete(B, closest_idx)
    return result
```

```
#GPU execution - most efficient method found in stackoverflow!
@nb.njit('int_[:](float32[:],float32[:])', parallel=True)
def method2(A,B):
    mB = B.shape[0]
    output = np.empty(A.shape[0], dtype=np.int_)

    # Parallel loop
    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        rowA = A[i]
        rowB = B

        index_rowB = np.argsort(rowB)
        sorted_rowB = rowB[index_rowB]

        idxs = np.searchsorted(sorted_rowB, rowA)
        left = np.fabs(rowA - sorted_rowB[np.maximum(idxs-1, 0)])
        right = np.fabs(rowA - sorted_rowB[np.minimum(idxs, mB-1)])
        prev_idx_is_less = (idxs == mB) | (left < right)

        output[i] = index_rowB[idxs - prev_idx_is_less]

    return output
```

Both methods takes years for execution for the length of my arrays!!!

Comment: What should it do, if the values in `data_array` are completely different from the values in `test_array`? What exactly do you mean by "based on"? What is the logic that needs to be used?

Comment: Given the search space grows as `n!` why don't you just sort each list, pair up the elements, and then order by `test_array`.  It likely to give a very good approximation (if not the actual answer)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It needs to find the smallest difference value by finding the difference between all elements in the other array, say 'a' is value in data_array, [b,c,d] are values in test_array and min(|a-b|, |a-c|, |a-d|) should be calculated and the corresponding index position is obtained. Based on these indices, I need to arrange the data_array.

Comment: It is not at all clear what the procedure is. I think you have code in your post, but it is not formatted as code and so unreadable. Please take the time to learn how to format your post appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got this. Apologies if I've not fully understood your question.

My solution:

1. Create dataframe with test data (saves original order of test_array through index)
2. Sort the dataframe by the test data
3. Add a column with sorted data_array
4. Sort the index to get original order of test_array.

This assumes that the smallest unique difference is the same as pairing the arrays by rank. Check that this is accurate for your use case.
I expect this to be quick given its low complexity.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data_array=[4.4, 7.2, 10.1, 1.1, 5.5, 8.3, 2.2, 6.2, 3.3, 9.1, 1.3]
test_array=[2, 5, 9, 4, 10, 8, 7, 3, 6, 1, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'test':test_array})
df.sort_values(by='test',inplace=True)
df['data']=sorted(data_array)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df['data']

#output: 2.2, 5.5, 9.1, 4.4, 10.1, 8.3, 7.2, 3.3, 6.2, 1.1, 1.3
```

Comment: this solution worked for my case and it is also fast for even lengthy arrays :) Thank you